# Conflict using both Caffeine and Redis in Quarkus application

Tags: caching, redis, quarkus, caffeine-cache

My Quarkus application has a cache name "features" using Caffeine configured under this key `quarkus.cache.caffeine.featureFlag.*`.

After adding Redis configurations, my application couldn't start, it says:
`Unable to determine the value type for 'features' Redis cache. An appropriate configuration value for 'quarkus.cache.redis.features.value-type' needs to be set`

How to tell Quarkus that `features` cache name uses Caffeine not Redis?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.